# Encrypt of an audio stream in AES from android-client to java-server

Tags: java, android, sockets, encryption

I'm trying to develop an android app that can send an encrypted audio stream in AES to a java server.

The audio stream is periodically sent as bytearray through a socket to a server. My idea was to encrypt the bytearray in AES and send it to the server which will decrypt it.

The class that encrypt/decrypt is the following:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class AESEncr {

    static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    static String encryptionKey = "0123456789abcdef";

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    }
}
```

The class has been locally tested on android ( that is, at the moment of sending the stream I do:

```
out.write(AESEncr.decrypt(AESEncr.encrypt(bArray)));
```

in the android code and the server can easily manage the stream, which make me think that there aren't algorithmic problems into the encrypt/decrypt methods). The streams used are of the type OutputStream and InputStream.

The data is actually sent in this way:

```
out.write(AESEncr.encrypt(bArray));
```

The server receives the data in the following way:

```
while(in.read(receiveData)!=-1){
    receiveData = AESEncr.decrypt(receiveData);
    /*Playback of the current stream*/
}
```

When the server tries to decode the bytearray, I receive the following error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

I tried to make the two parts treat the bytearray in Base64, but I obtain the same result.

How can I solve this problem? It is possible that both the socket does not send the data correctly? Are there other methods to encrypt an audio stream from an android client to a java server? I thought I could use a SSL, but I'm not sure this is the right choice (and considering the software I don't even think I can use it.).

Comment: Did you try decrypting what you're sending in your client? just to make sure your methods are ok, before checking other possible problems.
Also adding the way you're sending this data might help.

Comment: Curiously, [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) appears to suggest that PKCS5Padding is not compatible with AES, even though the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) clearly list it as a valid option. In any case, have you tried switching it to PKCS7Padding?

Comment: @adelphus They are specified differently, but they are implemented in exactly the same way. The name of "PKCS5Padding" was used for historical reasons (DES) and is fully compatible with PKCS7Padding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I meant     out.write(AESEncr.decrypt(AESEncr.encrypt(bArray))); . I used it to test the methods of the class, of course, to send the steam encrypted I'll use     out.write(AESEncr.encrypt(bArray));

Comment: @ArtjomB. done. Any solution to this?

Comment: @UdiIdan As I wrote in the question, I did this test and everythings works properly.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it.

Comment: How are you reading from the stream and decrypting it? You need to decrypt the *exact* chunk that you encrypted. It can't be bigger or smaller if you're sending multiple ciphertexts through the same stream.

Comment: @ArtjomB.I edited the question adding the way the server receives the data and decrypts. The receiveData bytearray is larger than the data that get, so I don't think there are problems of size.

Comment: 'The server receives the data in the following way:'. That way is not ok. As Artjom already said you should only decrypt if the chunck you received is exactly the sent chunk. You really have to check if you receive the same amount of bytes as send. Your client should first send an integer indicating the amount of following bytes. The server should first read that integer and then read as many bytes as told by that integer. The 'send size first protocol' is very common in client-server programming. Nothing new.

Comment: You can find out easy what goes wrong by logging all the sent chunck sizes in your sender and also the received sizes on receiver.

Comment: By the way, since you're using a stream, then you really should be streaming data that you encrypt. Look into `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`. If you don't want to use those (and I would understand), use the `update()` method of the `Cipher` object. Encrypting the chunks separately is inefficient, because that would result in repeated key schedule (AES internal operation). Instead you should be using only one "static" `Cipher` during the whole transmission.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you. Using these stream, any data that passes through it is encrypted right? Can you give me some examples of this stream?

Comment: Yes, the data is encrypted or decrypted when passing through the streams. I haven't worked with them, so I'm not comfortable providing any examples. One problem with them is that they silently swallow some exceptions which you probably want to look out for.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Using this stream I must  send the portion of bytes to read, in order to have a good decryption?

Comment: @greenapps The chunck size of the sender is 1296, but the server receive only 1280, and I explicitly set the in.read() function to read the chunk of size 1296.

Comment: Well there you see. All normal behavior. You have to do a read again requesting for the remaining bytes. Nothing new.